# Calculate when a browser can slowing down

Tags: browser, cpu, ram, slowdown

Is it possible to calculate within a reasonable approximation, how many tabs a browser can open before the system slows down, according to the components of a computer (ram, cpu, video card etc..), to the average thickness of the currently opened web pages, active processes, and system-wide machine usage (i.e. memory, cpu)?

A possibile use case could be to show a user, which pages are using more resources than others so she could easily optimize the performances.

Comment: It might be theoretically possible, but the real world is usually an edge case. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But I'll confess its not as stupid a request as it sounds.